# Why my Discord Bot keeps crashing in heroku?

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I uploaded my bot, made in Node.js to github and it's connected to heroku. When I deploy it it starts and it works but after 2 or 3 minutes it crashes and stops with:
`heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

I already tested `heroku logs` but it doesn't show anything more helpful.

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Make sure you are not using a web dyno

Comment: how do I deactivate dynos (I don't know what a dyno is)

Comment: A quick search for 'heroku dynos' came up with [this](https://www.heroku.com/dynos) and [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos).

Answer (score 0):

did you put a Procfile file containing :

```html
worker: node index.js
```

replacing index with the name of your main file.

Answer (score -1):

Hi there you can fix this issue by clearing the cache of the discord. Other solution to issue is mentioned [here](https://droidtheory.com/fix-discord-keeps-crashing/) check